# Clic en Select Option en PHP

Tags: php

Hola a todos tengo este select que carga desde una tabla de de una base de datos, la pregunta es alguien me puede de decir como programar esta lista, para que al dar clic o un enter sobre una opcion me cargue el registro en la misma pagina.

Anticipadamente agradezco su valiosa ayuda.

```
<form  action = "consultadirecta.php" method="POST" > 
Clave <input type="tex" name="txtclave" ></br>
<select name="txtregion"> <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>

<?php        

`include ("conexion.php");

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tabla1 GROUP BY Region 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1" ) ;`

while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    echo '<option 
    value="'.$valores['REgion'].'">'.$valores['REgion'].'</option>';

}

?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Lo que necesitas es usar Ajax a traves de JavaScript. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la verdad estoy empezando en esto de php y no entiendo ajax, abra alguna forma mas sencilla?

Comment: Existen frameworks front-end que podrían hacerlo pero todos (hasta donde yo se) usan ajax y probablemente sean mas complejos de entender y aprender.

Comment: Entonces se tiene que usar ajax

Comment: Si, es la forma estandar de realizar peticiones entre cliente y servidor sin recargar la página.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar jQuery para detectar cuando seleccionas una opción del campo select. La verdad es de que cada problema tiene su propia solución y sino pones código difícilmente podremos ayudarte por lo que solo me queda guiarte un poco.

```
$(document).on('change','#idSelect',function(){
           //Aquí puedes mandar a llamar una función que haga el llamado ajax hacia el backend con la información que necesitas y deberás manipularla.
});
```

[Puedes guiarte en este enlace para checar como se configura ajax.](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method)

[Cómo enviar un formulario a PHP](https://www.formget.com/form-submission-using-ajax-php-and-javascript/)

Saludos

Comment: Muy amable por tu respuesta y tu aporte  Daniel Luna